# Java BitSet performance

Tags: java, bitset

I have two BitSet of million size in Java and I want to perform operation like andNot on the two BitSets. 
How is the performance for the same? 
Should I do it in real time or do it in separate process?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need such large bitsets?

Comment: @fge: Consider I have 1 million unique records and for a given user I have maintained which all records he has touched. I need to get untouched records for the given user

Comment: Uh, and don't you think a dedicated storage engine may be faster at doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is use of your L3 cache in terms of performance.  I suspect your BitSets fit in an L3 cache so no matter what else you do I suggest you keep things as simple as possible.  If your BitSets don't fit into your L3 cache, your only option is to by a bigger L3 cache or buy more sockets (in one machine or more than one)  Multiple processes are more likely to make it slower.